# Xorg freeze with external monitor on Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 ( Debian linux )

Tags: debian, xorg, video

I have as issue with my ASUS X80L laptop ( system config: Celeron M 550, 2Gb RAM, Intel Mobile GM965/GL960 video ). I'm running Debian testing on it with X.Org v 1.12.1.902 and XFce 4.8.

Every 10-20 minutes my X-server is freeze for 20-60 seconds w/o any reason ( usually I'm using only IDE and opera browser for web-dev ).
During freeze-time I can only move cursor and hear music on background.

Watching my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` on a tty1 I see repeated entries (it repeats every time while X is not respond):

```
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
(II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
(II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
(II) intel(0): EDID vendor "GSM", prod id 17503
(II) intel(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
(II) intel(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
(II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
(II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
(II) intel(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
(--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
```

Full log http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=92JXreRW

Output of `lspci -v` http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=QXWqsxZu

Xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us,uk(winkeys)"
    Option         "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_caps_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "LG"
    ModelName      "L1752HR"
    Option         "DPMS" "false"

    Modeline       "1280x800x0.0"   69.30  1280 1328 1360 1405  800 803 809 822 -hsync -vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "intel"

    VideoRam       524288
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24

    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I can't solve this issue by using google and forums.
What's wrong?

**upd.**
I'm performed test using laptop w/o external display, but I'm still get save freezes and errors.
Here is dmesg output http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xf9B1jgh

Also, every time after that freezes my keyboard setting fall back to default, defined in `xorg.conf`. My xfce4 setting defines locales chagne by alt+caps, and left-alt as a compose-key.
But it turn alt+shift to change locale, with no compose key.

**upd 2**
After changing my `xorg.conf` by adding some optioons regarding EDID

```
Option "UseEDID" "False"
Option "IgnoreEDID" "1"
```

There are no more error message in dmesg, but sometimes X-server freeze for the time (now for shorter time). And I've got some messages in my `Xorg.0.log`

```
[157600.245] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[157605.263] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[157605.263] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[157605.409] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "LPL", prod id 297
[157605.409] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[157605.409] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1328 1360 1405  800 803 809 822 -hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz eP)
[157605.810] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
```

Answer (score 1):

What messages are you getting by executing following command:

```
dmesg | tail
```

after that freeze?

Also make sure that your xorg.conf does exists, if not, create one (e.g. `sudo Xorg -configure`) or customize it by playing with the following options (in your Device section):

```
Option "UseEDID" "False"
Option "IgnoreEDID" "1"
Modes "1152X864" "1024X768" "800x600"
```

If this doesn't help, try to edit your: /etc/default/grub file and change (or add) the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

If above solution doesn't help, then try to upgrade your distro to the latest version:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

restart your machine and check if it's solved.

---

See some of the following articles for some guidance:

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Media_Accelerator_X3100

http://wiki.debian.org/XStrikeForce/HowToRandR12

http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/15374/solved-error-edid-checksum-is-invalid-remainder-is-130/

Comment: I've just got two 'freezes' in a couple minutes, here is dmesg output http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xf9B1jgh

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Disabling UseEDID and turning on IgnoreEDID seems work.

Comment: Unfortunately "IgnoreEDID" doesn't help me to get rid of a freezes.

Comment: Try to upgrade your distro by: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade